# Spell checker for Google Docs for languages other than English

Tags: google-docs, spell-check

Recently I became a huge fan of Google Docs despite all the deficiencies. But there's one thing that really repels me from writing anything in language other than English, namely poor spell checker. It does not recognize about 10-20% of words in Polish and quite a few French words too, which is quite a big number I should say.

Have been looking for chrome extension that could do the job instead, but have found nothing at all.

Is there any way I could extend Google Docs (or get a Chrome Extension) dictionary with a few other dictionaries rather than adding not recognized words on a one by one basis?

It's been almost a year since pax's comment and I still hope this issue will be resolved soon.

To be very clear on what I am expecting to get take a look at the article from a Polish [online newspaper](http://dorzeczy.pl/wegry-jak-lego/), that is an article written by people who know the language really well by definition. It's about Hungary so yes, there are some words that might not have been recognized, but there are about 20 legitimate Polish words that have been marked as misspelled. If in doubt check [online polish dictionary](http://sjp.pl)

Yes, I set the language to Polish.

As I mentioned in the comment, vim with polish dictionary can do a lot better; without the AI stuff that is sort of missing the whole point of a spell checker.

[image]

Comment: Have you been adding the words to your dictionary? I'd expect after not too long a time you would cover just about all of the words you use.

Comment: I probably would be better off changing the header from Polish to Non English.

Comment: I understand that the spell checker in Google Docs is based on the dictionary built from indexing the web. (You know, the magic that happens when you misspell a word in your search term.) I'm guessing that languages that aren't as well-represented as English will not have as-complete dictionaries.

Comment: @Al Everett, Could understand that, but I'm not talking about sophisticated Natural Language Processing tools. I'm talking about the very basic dictionary that every spell checker has. I downloaded a polish dictionary for vim and it works just perfect. It seems to me that Google Docs spell checker is over-engineered.

Comment: As it seems, for now, [Google Docs only provides spellcheck for English](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57859) - although one can choose the language of the document. Which is massively lame.

Comment: @pax you should post this as an answer, as it is referenced and totally settles the question for now.

Comment: I also miss this very basic spell check in "non-English" languages.

Answer (score 4):

One way to have your "dictionary" include spellings from other languages is to translate the document into the language you desire. This will create a copy of the document in the language you choose.

[image: Tools menu with "Translate document..." selected]

[image: Translate document pop-up set to Spanish]

Though this way may produce some weird results, I find that once translated the "spell check" does provide corrections with the translated language, though it will also still correct English spellings.

An example of one weird result I've seen while translating from an English document to a German one had  `Sprechen sie deutsch` translated to `Do you speak English`. Though, it appears this may have happened because the document had been translated multiple times between languages before translating it back to English, where I added the line which spell check corrected it for German spelling.

Another weird result was the translation failing to separate words causing the "spell check" to flag the word, but it did give the correction in the language it was translated to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have further clarified my question.

Answer (score 3):

For the French language, [Druide Antidote](http://www.druide.com/a_correcteur.html) and [Cordial](http://www.synapse-fr.com/correcteur_orthographe_grammaire.htm) are the best (spell + grammar + conjugation checkers) and have integration for Google Chrome. But they aren't free. Otherwise, [Spell Checker for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spell-checker-for-chrome/jfpdnkkdgghlpdgldicfgnnnkhdfhocg?hl=en) is a free extension that supports French.

For Polish, you can try using the [built-in spell checker](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95604?hl=en) in Chrome (you can even provide your own dictionary, but there is a Polish one by default):

- Go to Settings.
- Click Show advanced settings.
- In the "Languages" section, click Languages and input settings.
- In the Languages and Input dialog that appears, use the "Enable spell checking" checkbox to turn the spell-checker on or off.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have further clarified my question.

Comment: Can you explain why those extensions don't do the job?

Comment: Franck, spell checker for chrome extension works better than the built-in one (you can compare the text from the line) but it's external to the document.  I am talking really basic, fundamental spell checker running on a document that has been with Microsoft Word for last 20 years.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's external to the document."?

Comment: It doesn't work on documents in Google Docs.You have to copy the text over and work there.I want to know how can I do a spell check on the document.If I am to leave Google Docs to do spell checking I can use other services like Gmail.Even tough it's better than built-in one it seems to me that this extension uses statistical approach too as it struggles with common words like "międzynarodowy" (=international): http://i.imgur.com/qlaUsuh.png. I feel that I am demanding too much but see vim for comparison: http://i.imgur.com/nLEnpWP.png (only Hungarian words are highlighted)

Comment: Good point, I see the issue now.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to change your proofing language is to set it under `File` menu.

In this case you'll use the same document, without translation. You can pick the spelling checker of your choice (even dialects like Deutsch, Schweizerdeutsch) that Google supports.

[image: Set Google Doc Proofing Language]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As specified in the question, the language was set the the same as the spell checked text. 
Problem was somewhere else, namely with poor spell checker that was subsequently replaced with new version of Google Docs last year.
Three years ago when I asked this question, Google still was unable to do a simple spell check in many non-English languages. Today they can.

Comment: Yes, they're definitely evolving. Actually I am using the Hungarian spell checker and it is quite OK. Not the best, but acceptable, at least warns about the typos.